# from an ec2 instance spin up another ec2 instance and push a csv file on it

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, boto

I am trying to run multiple algorithms on multiple data sets available in a csv file. So I would want to scale up ec2 instances so all the instances can run in parallel on different datasets. I am trying to figure out a way to scale up ec2 instances and paste different datasets(.csv) to each instance. 
Note: I don't want to implement a queuing system and use a database.

Comment: Think about the configuration management tools, such as ansible, puppet, chef, salt,  to archive your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern typically involves:

- **A central system that 'pushes' work** into some form of storage that is accessible to all instances, such as an Amazon SQS queue
- An **Auto Scaling group** that maintains the desired number of Amazon EC2 instances (with optional rules to change the number of instances based on a metric)
- A **startup script** on each instance that runs your application
- An application that **pulls work from the queue**, processes it, stores the results somewhere (eg in a database or in Amazon S3) and then repeats the process

You should take your source data (eg CSV files) and push individual chunks of work in the Amazon SQS queue. The message can either contain the actual input data, or it could contain a link to a file stored in Amazon S3.

The application running on each of the Amazon EC2 instances would request a message from the queue, retrieve the source data if it was stored in Amazon S3, process the data, store the output *somewhere*, then tell the SQS queue to delete the message. If the application fails, then Amazon SQS will automatically place the message back on the queue after a pre-determined 'invisibility' period.

**Without a database or a queue**

You say that you don't want to use a database or a queueing system, but you don't say why this is the case. If it is a desire to avoid cost, then please note that a queue would cost you only a few cents. A database can also be very low-cost.

You could use Amazon S3 to store work, with each application instance grabbing a file to process. The application would delete the file, process the work, then store the result into Amazon S3.

You would, effectively, be using Amazon S3 as a pseudo-database and work queue.

The problems with this approach are that the application could fail, resulting in lost work, and multiple instances of the application could attempt to grab the same work item at the same time, causing duplicated work. Amazon SQS helps avoid both of these situations.

**Pushing files to instances**

Your question asks about pushing CSV files to instances. This is a very poor architectural design and should be avoided. Rather than having a central system "push" work, it is always more robust to have the individual workers "pull" work, since they are the ones that know when more work can be consumed. It is also much simpler, because pushing information to an instance requires a robust method of receiving the work, which can be much more complex to create than simply providing a fully-managed, centralized queue.

**Spinning up a 'worker' EC2 instance**

Worst case, you could spin-up a separate EC2 instance for each 'chunk' of work. If the work definition is small, you could pass it as part of the User Data. If the work definition is large, then store it in Amazon S3 and pass a reference to the instance -- either via User Data, or via a Tag that is assigned to the instance upon launch. (The instance could inspect its own tags at startup, retrieve the reference, then retrieve the data from S3.)

The downside to this approach is that EC2 is charged on an hourly basis, so having each instance do a single 'chunk' of work could work out more expensive, especially if they only require a small fraction of an hour to operate.

**Use AWS Lambda**

Instead of using Amazon EC2, another option is to use AWS Lambda functions. An elegant method would be to store each chunk of work as an object in Amazon S3. This can then trigger an AWS Lambda function that processes the input file and stores the output somewhere (eg in another S3 bucket). Please note, however, that Lambda functions can only run for a maximum of 5 minutes, which might not be applicable for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an elaborated answer. I agree on each specific being pointed out by you. Just to give you an idea the reason behind avoiding the queue and database is because the code is going to be part of data pipeline where a queuing system is already implemented so adding another queue could be point of failure. For database as there are around 100K similar tasks so querying would add an overhead. So I was trying to find a way where I can just post the chunk of data on spin up so an instance can work on dedicated tasks.

Comment: Worst case, you could spin-up a separate EC2 instance for each chunk of work, passing the work (or an S3 reference to the work) via User Data. However,  that isn't very robust.

Comment: Agreed. Do you have link to any such example that can be useful?
Also after doing a bit of research I think one more solution could be to create separate EBS for each instance, copy related file and then attach the volume to instance. Let me know if that's doable or if you have any useful resource on that.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some details. I would recommend against using EBS to transfer data -- much better to share data via Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to John's great answer also look at using [AWS Batch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html).